# Android - Fragment - Communication from Main Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have problem with Fragments in android (i'm beginer with fragmetns).

There are files in my project:

[Main Activity and Fragment](http://pastebin.com/a3WYraT2)

[Main Activity Layout and Fragment layout](http://pastebin.com/trgxKKZG)

In Main Activity I have problem on line 32. To **fra** comes null pointer. I'm looking for the third day, and no example of it did not help me.

I need to get Fragment, because i want to get/set data in fragment from Main activity.

Someone please help me? Thank you

Comment: Go through [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) also if you are trying to do something with the UI when the fragment is not in foreground, I dont think it will work. Instead you can populate static variables using the message passing paradigm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `onCreate()` method should look like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings_form);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        SettingFragment_Page1 fragment = new SettingFragment_Page1();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, fragment, "tag");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();


        SettingFragment_Page1 fra = (SettingFragment_Page1) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("tag");

        fra.setButtonText("aaaa");
        Log.d("I: ", fra.getButtonText());
    }
}
```

Try this. It should work now.

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks, but in fragment is now problem, mButton si null, i try to solve it